# Want to show result after apex batch process is completed

Tags: apex, batch, salesforce-id

I need to show a alert message after the batch process is completed. For that i have create a static boolean varible in a class and in my batch process finish i am calling this varible and changing the value of the boolean varible, when the process is completed. I am using a apex button to run the batch process. The value of the boolean is get changed but i am not able to show the message when the process is completed. my batch file

```
 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    System.debug('Batch Process Completed in finish 1');
    BatchUpdate_info.Updateresult = true;
    System.debug('Batch Process Completed in finish 2');
    system.debug('Batch process result ' + BatchUpdate_info.Updateresult);
}
```

}
static var

```
public class BatchUpdate_info {
```

public static boolean Updateresult = false; 
 }

VF page to run the batch file

```
<apex:page controller="ctrl_ConatctBatch">
<apex:messages />
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="Run Batch Process" action="{!getRunBatch}" />  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class ctrl_ConatctBatch
{

public String getRunBatch() 
 {
     contact_BatchProcess cb = new contact_BatchProcess ();
     Database.executeBatch(cb, 200);
     System.debug('Result : In getRunBatch function');
     if(BatchUpdate_info.Updateresult == true){
        System.debug('Batch Process Completed');
        ApexPages.Message dupeMsg = new      ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Batch Process Completed');
        BatchUpdate_info.Updateresult = false;
        System.debug('Batch Update result ' + BatchUpdate_info.Updateresult);
     }

     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

---

### Update on 2016-01-19

The link previously shared was of un secure site so removed that, so here's briefly what to do:

1. Get the Id of the Async Apex Job record:  `Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchClass);`
2. Query `AsynxApexJob` to get information about the Batch Process particularly the `Status`, `Extended Status`, `Job Items Processed`, `Number of Errors`, and `Total Job Items`.  For more information about `AsyncApexJob`, see the [DeveloperForce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com).
3. Update your Visualforce Page or Lightning App with the queried `AsyncApexJob` data.  There are many UIs available for Progress Bars particularly using HTML5.  Essentially you want to show the % done as `Job Items Processed` / `Total Job Items`.  And don't forget to have a way to show if the Batch failed (like turning the Progress Bar red or something -- maybe display the `Status` and `Extended Status`...).  Links about Progress Bars:  [HTML5 Progress from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/), [Bootstrap 3 Progress Bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress)

---

### Update on 2016-01-22

Found an answer of mine that has the code from the original link:

[Best practices for monitoring Scheduled Apex and Batch Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17569/best-practices-for-monitoring-scheduled-apex-and-batch-apex/17575#17575)

Comment: Thats a really good find!

Comment: the link is taken down!  What is the solution for this?

Comment: Answer is updated

Answer (score 2):

The better approach for this would be use an email alert to send to the User once a batch is completed .

If you want on the page an action poller or streaming API is the only way to detect this and show on to the page the moment batch completes .

Comment: Yes i know to use email, but i like to show a message on VF page after the batch process is completed, is this possible.